# Microsoft Teams bot finding message sender id

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

We have built a teams app that can be used in the group chat. So, basically any user can do
@

At the server side, we want to get the sending user and respond to the sent text based on who sent it. The code to get users in the conversation looks like below:

```
 const connector = context.adapter.createConnectorClient(context.activity.serviceUrl);
            const response = await connector.conversations.getConversationMembers(context.activity.conversation.id);
            functions.logger.log("conversation members are:", response)
```

The response returns an array of all the users in the conversation with below structure

```
[
  {
    "id": "29:1a-Xb7uPrMwC2XqjMEHCC7ytV2xb2VUCqTA-n_s-k5ZyMCTKIL-ku2XkgbE167D_5ZbmVaqQxJGIQ13vypSqu-A",
    "name": "Neeti Sharma",
    "objectId": "718ab805-860c-43ec-8d4e-4af0c543df75",
    "givenName": "Neeti",
    "surname": "Sharma",
    "email": "xxx@xxxx.xxx",
    "userPrincipalName": "xxxx@xxxx.xxx",
    "tenantId": "xxx-xx-xx-xxxxxx-x",
    "userRole": "user"
  },
  {
    ...
  }
]
```

The above response does not indicate who is the sender of the message in the group chat. How do we find that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure the *exact* syntax for Node (I work mostly in C#), but basically on the `context.activity` object there is a `from` property (i.e. `context.activity.from`), which is of type `ChannelAccount` (DotNet reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.connector.channelaccount?view=botbuilder-dotnet-3.0), but it's very similar for Node). That will give you, at least, Name and AadObjectId. What you're using right now is `getConversationMembers`, which gives you *everyone* in the entire Channel, not just that particular message/thread.

Comment: let me try that out

Comment: i can do a heck like matching name with conversation member result name. what i ideally need is the email of the sender

Comment: is object id unique to each sender ? as if yes then instead of name I can match that one.

Comment: yes, object is unique. AadObjectId is basically the user's Azure Active Directory user id. If you want email, then yes, definitely, you can simply match the activity.from to the getconversationmembers results

Answer (score 1):

turnContext.Activity.From.Id is also unique to each user. You can use that property too. Email is tough to get in any other events than the MembersAdded event.